# Getting ENOENT running a binary copied into my Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which looks something like this

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

# ARGs and LABELs...

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

COPY src/scripts scripts/
COPY src/scripts/update_mmdb.sh /etc/periodic/weekly/update_mmdb

RUN /etc/periodic/weekly/update_mmdb
RUN mkdir -p /root/myapp/bin
COPY src/docker/bin/program_running_in_a_separate_process /root/myapp/bin/
WORKDIR /root/myapp


# Some more COPY-ing

COPY src/myapp/docker/cmd.sh /

CMD /cmd.sh
```

When I go to run my container I get an `ENOENT` error when my app attempts to spin up `program_running_in_a_separate_process`.

I investigated by doing `docker exec -it myapp sh` and attempting to run the binary directly.  I successfully was able to `stat` it:

```
# stat program_running_in_a_separate_process
  File: program_running_in_a_separate_process
  Size: 14689327        Blocks: 28696      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 39h/57d Inode: 15073498    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-01-14 01:08:09.000000000
Modify: 2020-01-14 01:08:09.000000000
Change: 2020-01-14 01:08:09.000000000
```

, it came up when I ran `ls` from `/root/myapp/`, I even ran `chmod +x` to be sure, but sure enough when I go to run `program_running_in_a_separate_process`, I get `sh: ./program_running_in_a_separate_process: not found`

How could this be?

Comment: Wrong architecture?  Missing shared library dependencies?  It’s a script of some form but the interpreter isn’t installed?

Comment: It's a compiled Go binary.  And to clarify, I'm attempting to just run the binary from the commandline, the file exists, but when I do `./my_binary` I'm told the file isn't found

Comment: It shouldn't be the wrong arch either, I compiled it on my Debian x86-64 box.